# Type-casting in C for standard function

Tags: c, casting, macros

I am working on a C project (still pretty new to C), and I am trying to remove all of the warnings when it's compiled.

The original coders of this project have made a type called dyn_char (dynamic char arr) and it's an unsigned char * type. Here's a copy of one of the warnings:

> warning: argument #1 is incompatible with prototype: prototype:
>   pointer to char : ".../stdio_iso.h", line 210     argument : pointer to
>   unsigned char

They also use lots of standard string functions like `strlen();` so the way that I have been removing these warnings is like this:

```
strlen((char *)myDynChar);
```

I can do this but some of the files have hundreds of these warnings. I could do a Find and Replace to search for `strlen(` and replace with `strlen((char*)`, but is there a better way?

Is it possible to use a Macro to do something similar? Maybe something like this:

```
#define strlen(s) strlen((char *)s)
```

Firstly, would this work? Secondly, if so, is it a bad idea to do this?

Thanks!

Comment: The easy solution (if it wouldn't mess anything up) would be to redefine `dyn_char` to be `char *`, rather than `unsigned char *`. Is that possible?

Comment: Good point, I think this would cause some other problems, I am not sure though. There are comments in the code that indicate they have thought about doing this, but for some reason they haven't. Perhaps, they just haven't focused much on these warnings in the past :)

Comment: Are the calls to `strlen` already there (did they do this) ? I am asking because it might just be that you are using a type that is not meant to be used as string (`0`-terminated `char` array) for that purpose. Otherwise, if they really mean it like that, this is a design error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is an annoying problem, but here's my two cents on it.

First, if you can confidently change the type of `dyn_char` to just be `char *`, I would do that. Perhaps if you have a robust test program or something you can try it out and see if it still works?

If not, you have two choices as far as I can see: fix what's going into `strlen()`, or have your compiler ignore those warnings (or ignore them yourself)! I'm not one for ignoring warnings unless I have to, but as far as fixing what goes into strlen...

If your underlying type is `unsigned char *`, then casting what goes into `strlen()` is basically telling the compiler to assume that the argument, for the purposes of being passed to `strlen()`, is a `char *`. If `strlen()` is the only place this is causing an issue and you can't safely change the type, then I'd consider a search-and-replace to add in casts to be the preferable option. You *could* redefine `strlen` with a `#define` like you suggested (I just tried it out and it worked for me), but I would **strongly** recommend not doing this. If anything, I'd search-replace `strlen()` with `USTRLEN()` or something (a fake function name), and then use that as your casting macro. Overriding C library functions with your own names transparently is a maintainability nightmare!

Two points on that: first, you're using a different name. Second, you're using all-caps, as is the convention for defining such a macro.

Answer (score 1):

This may or may not work

`strlen` may be a macro in the system header, in which case you will get a warning about redefining a macro, and you won't get the functionality of the existing macro.

*(The Visual Studio stdlib does many interesting things with macros in `<string.h>`.  `strcpy` is defined this way:*

```
__DEFINE_CPP_OVERLOAD_STANDARD_FUNC_0_1(char *, __RETURN_POLICY_DST, __EMPTY_DECLSPEC, strcpy, _Pre_cap_for_(_Source) _Post_z_, char, _Dest, _In_z_ const char *, _Source))
```

*I wouldn't be surprised at all if #defining strcpy broke this)`*

Search and replace may be your best option.  Don't hide subtle differences like this behind macros - you will just pass your pain on to the next maintainer.

Instead of adding a cast to all the calls, you may want to change all the calls to `dyn_strlen`, which is a function you create that calls strlen with the appropriate cast.

Answer (score 1):

You can define a function:

`char *uctoc(unsigned char*p){ return (char*)(p); }`

and do the search replace `strstr(x` with `strstr(uctoc(x)`. At least you can have some type checking. Later you can convert `uctoc` to a macro for performance.